# How do I make an element appear after form submission?

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple, working form and I'd like to make a html element appear after the form has been sent and the page has reloaded.

What I have so far:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" First Name: $firstname \n Last Name: $lastname \n Phone: $phone \n Company: $company \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Client Webform";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

$result= '<p>Thanks!</p>'
?>
```

The form's action is set to the same php file. So it reloads the same page.

And below the submit button I have an echo of the result:

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```

Currently the $result is displayed on the webpage as soon as it loads, but I need it to appear only when the form is sent and the page reloads.

Apologies, I'm a beginner and this is probably really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a name to your submit button like below

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

or

```
<button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Submit </button>
```

then check is that button clicked and submitted your form like below

```
if( isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]) ){
   $result= '<p>Thanks!</p>';
}
```

or you can do that control with your other required fields like 'email', 'name'.

dont use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ }` because a page can hold more than one form and you can't detect which form submitted.

Comment: This was the best solution. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` it only if the method of request is `POST`. If the request type is `GET`, which usually means the page is accessed via a url, that should not be echoed. You can perform this check like below,

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   echo $result;
}
```

This will check if form has been submitted using POST method and you can print your message